# Click body to hide item

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a button that when clicked toggles the display of my list. However I would like to add an additional functionality so that when the body of the page is clicked, it will close the list. i.e. list is open - click anywhere else on the page but the list and it should close.

My initial attempt at this was:

```
$('body').click(function(){
    $('ul').slideUp();
});
```

the issue with this is, because the button is part of the body - when the button is clicked it opens the ul, but at the same time it's almost instantly slid back up because the body has been clicked.

The code below is pseudo code for `<button>view dropdown</button>`

```
<ul>
    <li>link 1</li>
    <li>link 2</li>
    <li>link 3</li>
</ul>

ul{
    display:none; 
  }

$('button'.click(function(){
     $('ul').toggle();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Checks to make sure the item you've clicked doesn't have that specific class:

```js
$('body').on('click', function(e) {
  if (!$(e.target).is('.myclass')) {
    $('.myclass').toggle();
  }
});
```

```css
body {
min-height:200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myclass">Some Content</div>
```

Or, if you need to check for child elements as well (For ul you will need this):

```js
$('body').on('click', function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).closest('.myclass').length === 0) {
    $('.myclass').toggle();
  }
});
```

```css
body {
min-height:200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="myclass">
  <li>link 1</li>
  <li>link 2</li>
  <li>link 3</li>
</ul>
```

This solution has the added benefit of not requiring ".myclass" to be part of the DOM at the point when the JS code is ran.

Comment: it's better to add a full code that we can test + some explanation too

Comment: "As of jQuery 3.0, .bind() has been deprecated. It was superseded by the .on() method for attaching event handlers to a document since jQuery 1.7, so its use was already discouraged."

Comment: Thanks, that one slipped, meant to write ".on"

Answer (score 0):

I solved  your problem. Check my  example.

Wrapper is like body.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#wrapper").click(function(event) {
    var myClass = $(event.target).hasClass("menu");
    if (myClass == true) {
      console.log("you clicked menu");

    } else {
      console.log("you clicked out of menu");

    }
  });
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <select class="menu" id="menu">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though checking for the source of the event (i.e. the `event.target`) is a viable way, I personally do not prefer that method because it relies too heavily on magic constants. In many use cases, we are checking the class/ID of the `event.target`, which means that they have to be manually updated whenever we change the markup of your page. This can present a maintenance issue in the long run.

A more preferable and actually simpler solution will simply to leverage on the fact that emitted events **bubble** upwards (i.e. from child to parent) until it hits the document object. Therefore, what you want to do is to:

1. Attach a click event listener to your button, but stop that click event from bubbling to the body using `.stopPropagation()`
2. Attach a click event listener to the document (not the `<body>`, since it might not have full viewport height)

This is a typical "click outside to close" behaviour that is specced out by many UI/UX designers.

In addition, instead of using `.toggle()` (which is deprecated), you should instead explicitly toggle a class that hides the `<ul>` element. Something like `.toggleClass('hidden')` and then using `.hidden { display: none; }` will suffice.

To translate that into code, you can do the following:

```
$('button').click(function(e) {

  // Prevent event from bubbling up to body
  e.stopPropagation();

  // We toggle the .hidden class
  $('ul').toggleClass('hidden');
});

// Attach to document instead of body
// ... as body might not be full height
$(document).click(function() {
  // Always hide
  $('ul').addClass('hidden');
});
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('button').click(function(e) {
  
    // Prevent event from bubbling up to body
    e.stopPropagation();
  
    // We toggle the .hidden class
    $('ul').toggleClass('hidden');
  });
  
  // Attach to document instead of body
  // ... as body might not be full height
  $(document).click(function() {
    // Always hide
    $('ul').addClass('hidden');
  });
});
```

```css
ul.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="hidden">
  <li>link 1</li>
  <li>link 2</li>
  <li>link 3</li>
</ul>
<button type="button">Toggle ul element</button>
```

Comment: Please review this article for why stopPropogation is dangerous to use for this, it can cause even worse maintenance issues:
https://css-tricks.com/dangers-stopping-event-propagation/

Comment: @ErickMaynard I beg to differ—to each his own. I basically do not like encoding magic constants in my code, as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add event listeners to check which element was clicked to toggle the display of your list.

HTML:

```
<button class="button">view dropdown</button>
<ul class="myList">
    <li class="listItems">link 1</li>
    <li class="listItems" >link 2</li>
    <li class="listItems" >link 3</li>
</ul>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).click(function(event) {
    var target = event.target.className;
    var isVisible = $('.myList').css('display');
    if (target != "listItems" && target != "myList"  && isVisible == "block" && target != "button") {
      $('.myList').css('display', 'none');
    }
    else if(target == "button")
      $('.myList').toggle();
});
```

Css:

```
.myList {
  display: none;
}
```

Please check out this fiddle to view the working example of the code: http://jsfiddle.net/fymqrd7z/11/

Comment: If I can add a suggestion, I’d make the button toggle the list visibility, as opposed to just making it visible. It is what @J.Doe tried in his sample code and it’s the behavior I’d expect :-)

Comment: @agrm Oh yeah I forgot about that. Thanks! :D I've updated my answer now